# ffmpeg converting .mov to .ts, what bitstream filter to use?

Tags: ffmpeg

This is the command i have to convert `.mp4` to `.ts`

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts test.ts
```

I have `test.mov` that i want to convert to `.ts` .  What bitstream filter do i use for `.mov`? `h264_mp4toannexb`?

I tried with the same bitstream filter:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts test.ts
```

This error was returned

**Codec 'prores' (147) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'h264_mp4toannexb'. Supported codecs are: h264 (27)
Error initializing bitstream filter: h264_mp4toannexb
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --**

How do i solve?  Have i got to convert `.mov` to `.mp4` and then to `.ts`?

Comment: What's the purpose for storing ProRes in mpegts?

Answer (score 0):

The specified bitstream filter only works for H.264-compressed data. Your input file does not contain H.264 video, instead it contains ProRes-compressed video. I don't even think TS supports ProRes, so you'll need to re-compress the video. No bitstream filter is required for that, just specify `-c:v libx264` and [relevant compression parameters for H.264 encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).